# AWS does not display imported self-signed certs as options in load balancer creation page

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, ssl-certificate

I created a self signed certificate by running the following command:

```
openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:4096 -sha256 -nodes -keyout private.key -out public.crt -subj "/CN=example.com" -days 3650
```

I uploaded the resulting private key and public cert content to AWS' ACM. It imported the cert without a problem.

When I try to create a load balancer with a listener that uses the imported cert, however, I run into the issue where it won't display the imported cert as one of the options (one blotted out by the red line is not a self-signed cert).

[image: load balancer creation page]

I made sure that the cert is imported in the same region as the load balancer.

What steps could I be missing?

Comment: Did you import the certificates into the same AWS region that the load balancer is in?

Comment: yes i did. (character limit)